# Regex - more compact/elegant form

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to write [this regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/cK5wB6/3) (later [simplified form](https://www.regex101.com/r/cK5wB6/5)) in a more compact/ elegant/ systematic. PCRE or Python (newer engine) preferred. Shortly, I would like to capture each artery name (iliac, femoral, popliteal and so on), **regardless of the string between them** . Ideally, the resulted regex won't depend on any kind of regex flavor.

LE2: Even more simplified regex, but not working correctly: https://www.regex101.com/r/cK5wB6/7. I've eliminated `DEFINE` section - this was added only for modularity purposes, and `DEFINE` is not compatible with Python anyway (newer, v1 engine [added this feature](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)). I want **capture all the artery names**, equivalent of getting a vector of all artery names, regardless of number of names, or strings between them.

```
(arteries:.{0,25}?)
((?<art>iliac|femoral|popliteal|peroneal|tibial).*?)*
(?<artfinal>(?&art))
```

The problem is that some arteries are still not recognized correctly (at least visually). I'm trying to capture those names, without explicitly write capturing groups like in [this](https://www.regex101.com/r/cK5wB6/5).

LE4: The [last variant](https://www.regex101.com/r/cK5wB6/8) actually ignore all names, aside the 1st and the last two.[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with all this complexity. What are you doing that couldn't be done with `\b(iliac|femoral|popliteal|peroneal|tibial)\b`?

Comment: If you want it to work in all regex flavours, forget about elegant/ systematic, and go for compact. `(?(DEFINE) .. )` is not implemented in some regex flavours. You may as well use string variables to define each subpattern, and concatenate each to form the final pattern.

Comment: @Joe White: **regardless of the strings between arteries names** (added this later).

Comment: This will work, obviously: https://www.regex101.com/r/cK5wB6/5 (I was too tired to see I misspelled a word etc.)

Comment: So, <sep2> is useless. Question remains. Not sure whether could use some concepts from here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html

Comment: A regex can match multiple times within the same string, and as such it *will* match "regardless of the strings between", so I can't figure out what kind of distinction you're trying to draw here. Can you give examples of strings that you do want to match but that wouldn't be matched by the obvious simple regex?

Comment: `won't depend on any kind of regex flavor` Well, it won't work in all regex flavours as it is... `each artery name` What if there are 7 arteries?... `more compact/ elegant/` The question is still unclear to me

Comment: I want to recognize all the arteries given in the list (see definition of <art>)
For, instance, https://www.regex101.com/r/cK5wB6/6 won't recogize correctly all the artery names. The same artery could appear 1...n to and in any position. The strings between artery names could be anything of max. 25 chars. As of flqvors, let's stick with PCRE.

Comment: OK, i greatly simplified the regex: https://www.regex101.com/r/cK5wB6/7 in order to show what I'm trying to do. (Eliminated define section - this was added only for modularity purposes) I want to get a vector of all artery names, regardless of number, order of strings between them.

Comment: You can use `(?(DEFINE) )` in PCRE, it's only a matter of convinience. I posted an answer that I believe does it.

Comment: Why do you want to limit the number of characters to 25 (and not 10 or 40)?

Comment: This was an arbitrary number - i.e. maximum number of characters allowed between artery names. But I later remove this restriction eventually putting `.*?` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First, regex flavour independent pattern is a myth. Regex engines are different, have different features, and even a same pattern that only uses common tokens between two or more regex engines can return different results.

An example with the Python [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that has interesting features like the ability to use a set (`\L<arteries>` in the pattern) and the ability to store repeated capture groups:

```
import regex

s = '''arteries: jhjh iliac jdfd femoral 
arteries: sdsdsd iliac jdfd femoral fd d popliteal
arteries: hgv  popliteal,sddsdsds iliac  tibial nkjkknperoneal nkjkkn
arteries: iliac,  peroneal jm tibia nktibial nkjkkn
arteries: m bkjkjnperoneal vc peroneal fdfd femoral n tibial jnmmmmm tibial jnnjnjmbn n iliacbjk   
arteries:m bkjnkjnperoneal  mm femoral jnnbn n right femoralbjkkbb   jk'''

arteries_set = ['femoral', 'iliac', 'peroneal', 'tibial']

p = regex.compile(r'^arteries: (?: [^\w\n]* (?>\w+[^\w\n]+)*? (\L<arteries>) \M)+', regex.M | regex.I | regex.X, arteries=arteries_set)

for m in p.finditer(s):
    print(m.captures(1))
```

I voluntary removed the "less than 25 characters" condition to build a more efficient pattern, but feel free to replace `[^\w\n]* (?>\w+[^\w\n]+)*?` with `.{0,25}? \m`

*(`\m` and `\M` are word boundaries, respectively for the start and the end of a word)*

Comment: Or `(?>\w+[^\w\n]+){0,5}?` to limit to 5 words instead of 25 chars... Nice approach BTW

Answer (score 1):

> I want **capture all the artery names**,
>   The problem is that some arteries are still not recognized correctly (at least visually)

The problem with this regex:

```regex
((?<art>iliac|femoral|popliteal|peroneal|tibial).*?)*
```

is that the `group art` continuously overwrites its capture with the last match. This is an expected behaviour by design.

---

> I want to recognize all the arteries given in the list (see definition
>   of ) The same artery could appear 1...n to and in any position.
>   The strings between artery names could be anything of max. 25 chars.
>
> > As of flavors, let's stick with PCRE

Provided you're working with PCRE, instead of matching all occurences of arteries at once, I would suggest matching 1 artery at a time. And to achieve that, we can use [`\G` to match at the end of last match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).

#### Regex:

```regex
/\G                  # Match anchor (BoS or EoLastMatch)
(?:
    (?!^)            # With previous match
  |
    .*?              # Or first occurence
    arteries:        #  of arteries:
)

.{1,25}?             # Separated by max 25 chars

(?P<art>             # Group 1 (capture 1 artery)
      \b             # List of arteries
      (?:iliac|femoral|popliteal|peroneal|tibial)
      \b             #  in between word boundaries
                     # Modif: global, caseless, singleline, extra
)/gixs
```

This will capture each artery in group `art` (group 1).

- [DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/gP6kF3/1)

---

#### Notes about other flavours:

As for compatibility with other regex flavours, you could loop each match in your code to simulate `\G` (which is not implemented in almost any other flavour). Another option is to split the text with the expression:

```
(arteries:|\b(?:iliac|femoral|popliteal|peroneal|tibial)\b)
```

and then check the length of each token to guarantee there isn't more than 25 chars in between.

---

> the code will have to be migrated to Python one (not so distant) day

#### Update: Migrating to Python:

You can use `\G` in Python since the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) implemented it, but if you do use that module, take advantage if its ability to retrieve repeated captures from a group with the `.captures method`. Check [@CasimiretHippolyte's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841640/5290909), a perfect example of using captures in this case.

On the other hand, if you stick to the standard [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), I'd recommend looping each match to simulate the same behaviour.

**Code:**

```
import re

text = '''arteries: jhjh iliac jdfd femoral 
arteries: sdsdsd iliac jdfd femoral fd d popliteal
some arteries: hgv  popliteal,sddsdsds iliac  tibial nkjkknperoneal nkjkkn
arteries: iliac,  peroneal jm tibia nktibial nkjkkn
arteries: m bkjkjnperoneal vc peroneal fdfd femoral n tibial jnmmmmm tibial jnnjnjmbn n iliacbjk   
arteries:m bkjnkjnperoneal  mm femoral jnnbn n right femoralbjkkbb   jk'''
n = 0

pattern_from = re.compile( r'arteries:', re.I)
pattern_token = re.compile( r'.{1,25}?\b(iliac|femoral|popliteal|peroneal|tibial)\b', re.I)

for match_from in pattern_from.finditer(text):
    n = n + 1
    print( '\nMatch #%s:' % n, end="")
    match_token = pattern_token.match( text, match_from.end())
    while match_token:
        print( '[%s:%s]="%s" ' % (match_token.start(1), match_token.end(1), match_token.group(1)), end="")
        match_token = pattern_token.match( text, match_token.end())
```

**Output:**

```
Match #1:[15:20]="iliac" [26:33]="femoral" 
Match #2:[52:57]="iliac" [63:70]="femoral" [76:85]="popliteal" 
Match #3:[106:115]="popliteal" [125:130]="iliac" [132:138]="tibial" 
Match #4:[171:176]="iliac" [179:187]="peroneal" 
Match #5:[243:251]="peroneal" [257:264]="femoral" [267:273]="tibial" [282:288]="tibial" 
Match #6:[344:351]="femoral"
```

- [ideone DEMO](http://ideone.com/9j7RVt)

Comment: I wonder whether one could somehow use non-capturing inside of capturing or vice-versa. Tried this but not succeeded, too tired now.

Comment: Of course you can. But that has no impact whatsoever. You lost me there. Anyway, this regex should work for you. Let me know if there are any exceptions.

Comment: I would ask you for an alternative to `\G` - it's too specific (I asked to stick with PCRE, I know); the code will have to be migrated to Python one (not so distant) day.

Comment: Thank you. I know this could be done programatically (Python, java). I'd  want to write this entirely as regexes in order to achive some kind of composability _at regex level_ (declaratively), without  using the logic implemented imperatively or mixing them. In this ideal scenario, engine would receive a string as input and based only on specific regex, will recognize specific entities . But this will be hard to do anyway, so the mixing can't be avoided -it will be implemented in stages etc.

Comment: In Python, only 4 options: **1.** Use regex module. **2.** The code I posted (2 regexes). **3.** 1 pattern to get `"arteries...."` and another to get arteries names. **4.** Your first attempt: `(art1).*?(art2)?.*?(art3)?` up to a maximum number of groups defined